# Estimating the sum of a series within arbitrary certainty.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, estimation

Find the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^5} = a_n$ within three decimal places.

- The sum is estimated by $\displaystyle a_n \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^5}+R(n)$ where $R(n)$ is given by some value chosen between $\displaystyle \lim_{L \to \infty}\int_{n}^{L}\frac{1}{x^5}{\ \mathrm{d}x}$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{L \to \infty}\int_{n+1}^{L}\frac{1}{x^5}{\ \mathrm{d}x}$ inclusive, such that $\displaystyle \lim_{L \to \infty}\int_{n}^{L}\frac{1}{x^5}{\ \mathrm{d}x}$ is the maximum amount of error possible, and $\displaystyle \lim_{L \to \infty}\int_{n+1}^{L}\frac{1}{x^5}{\ \mathrm{d}x}$ is the minimum.
- Find: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1000} > \lim_{L \to \infty}\left.\frac{4}{x^4}\right\vert_{L}^{x} \implies \frac{1}{4000} > \frac{1}{x^4}-\lim_{L \to \infty}\frac{1}{L^4} \implies x^4 > 4000 \implies x \approx 8 \implies n=8$
- $a_n \approx \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{8}\frac{1}{n^5} + \lim_{L \to \infty}\int_{8}^{L}\frac{1}{x^5}{\ \mathrm{d}x}$

Is this approach to estimating the sum of the series appropriate?

Comment: It looks good (but you would want $x\geq 8$ instead of $x\approx 8$).

Comment: You'll want $x^{-4}/(-4),$ which should help.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Its solution is approaching 8 through values less than, but I see what you mean, and I'll make this correction, but is there an elegant way to say approximately greater than or equal to?

Comment: You don't need the approximately at all.  You need the ceiling, $\lceil\sqrt[4]{4000}\rceil=8$ (ceiling means round up).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Found it: $\lesssim$ and $\gtrsim$.

Comment: Actually, those symbols usually mean that the inequality is up to a constant multiple...